# How to disable (make read only) a cell in a DataGridView CheckBox column based on the value in other cells?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I found many similar questions and answers, but none helps me to solve my issue.

Please find my `DataGridView` below

[image]

What I want to do is to disable the check box if the *name* cell is empty at run time.

I tried many methods, but all the time the cell is disabled (read only) after I checked it.

I tried something like this:

```
private void sendDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (sendDGV.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value != null)
    {
        sendDGV.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
        sendDGV.Update();
    }
    else 
    {
        sendDGV.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
        sendDGV.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? The easiest way it to use jquery

Comment: @FlaviaObreja looks like a form application, not a web application.

Comment: mine is a form application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To handle the changes in column *name*, you can use the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event. The `e` parameter give you access to:

- `columnIndex` property, so you can test if the change is made on the *name* column (index 1).
- `rowIndex`property, so you retrieve the concerned row and change the values you want.

---

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //second column
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
        object value = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if (value != null && value.ToString() != string.Empty) {
            DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
        } else {
            DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As someone else noted, in order to have the `checkbox` disabled for new added rows (especially if the `AllowUserToAddRow` property is set to `true`), you can handle the `RowAdded` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quite old thread but I think you can use [CellBeginEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit(v=vs.110).aspx) event and Cancel the event on your condition. It is not disable the column it is rather cancel editing the desired column value.

1) subscribe for the event:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit  += DataGridView1OnCellBeginEdit;
```

2) event handler:

```
        private void DataGridView1OnCellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        var isTicked = this.dataGridView1.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[args.ColumnIndex].Value;

        args.Cancel = (isTicked is bool) && ((bool)isTicked);
    }
```

**I have used the event to get one inclusive checkbox.**

It means only one out of the three columns("None", "Read", "Full") can be "true"

[image]

Comment: this was elegant and new to me, love it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use DataGridView.CellValueChanged event:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() != "")
                dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = false;
            else
                dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

But in order to have the checkbox disbled at first, make sure you set the column to be ReadOnly using the designer and also, in the DataGridView.RowsAdded event, set the checkbox property ReadOnly = true for the new created row:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Flavia. 
But when i tried this example, I got null reference exception at the second 'if' condition. So I modified it to something like below
`if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value != null)`
 and it works good now.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, there is inbuilt **read only** property in Visual Studio, mark it as true

Comment: This changes the entire column, not the specific row in question.